# Best way to optimise a simple MYSQL COUNT query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table called signups and all I want is the `COUNT` of all signups where `is_email_verified` is true.

Attempt 1 results in an index scan:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM signups WHERE is_email_verified = true
```

Attemp 2 results in an index scan:

```
SELECT SUM(is_email_verified) from signups
```

Ideally I could just create an index on SUM(is_email_verified) but that functionality doesn't exist.

I could create a trigger and a summary table that auto updates when an email is verified but I feel like there should be an easier way that I am not seeing.

Any ideas?

Comment: No sure what optimisation you are looking for on a query filtering on a low selectivity boolean field where most of the values will be true anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT(*)` is notorious for needing to scan through the rows it's counting. Why? It's a long story involving [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and the integrity of concurrent updates.

You mentioned an index scan. I guess that means you have an index on `is_email_verified`. Your query, as written, will scan that index looking for the entries where that column is `1`.  It will not scan the part of the index where the value is zero. That's how it works. An sequential index scan here is probably more efficient than a table scan (less data to wrangle) but a scan is still necessary.

Your second query, `SUM(is_email_verified)` will have to scan the entire index. That means it will be a bit slower.

If the performance of this query is truly causing problems for your app, there are several strategies you can apply. You mentioned a series of triggers. You'll need them for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations on the table. That could work.

You could also arrange for some kind of application-side [memoization cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  That's a fancy way of saying "stash that number of verified users someplace and only update it once in a while".

Still, my (opinionated) advice is "don't worry about it now". Get your app working with straightforward easy-to-read queries like the one you showed us, and get yourself a growing base of happy users. You *will* have to do optimization work as your app gains users, and experience shows that it's really hard to guess exactly what you'll have to optimize.